Row attribute of radio group does not work in TextField.@mui/material@5.15.14
I want to use a TextField startAdornment with a radio group in it, but the row attribute doesn't work and the group is lined up vertically. I wonder how to make it horizontal.
import * as React from 'react';
import Radio from '@mui/material/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@mui/material/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import { InputAdornment, TextField } from '@mui/material';

export default function RadioButtonsGroup() {
  return (
    <TextField
      label="LABEL"
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <RadioGroup
              defaultValue='yes'
              row // doesn't work, why?
            >
              <FormControlLabel
                value="yes"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="Yes"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                value="no"
                control={<Radio />}
                label="No"
              />
            </RadioGroup>
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  );
}


I found. The radio group was too narrow and needed to be widened.
<RadioGroup
 defaultValue='yes'
 row // it works !
 sx={{
   width: 'max-content',
 }}
>

thank you.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I couldn't come up with a reason why row prop is not working with RadioGroup but following code can get you the desired result
<InputAdornment position="start">
    <RadioGroup
        defaultValue='yes'
        row // doesn't work, why?
    >
        <Stack direction={"row"}>
            <FormControlLabel
                 value="yes"
                 control={<Radio/>}
                 label="Yes"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
                 value="no"
                 control={<Radio/>}
                 label="No"
            />
        </Stack>
    </RadioGroup>

